# Selenium scrollIntoView() for Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver

I want to use selenium scrollIntoView() method for Internet Explorer but this

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", _webElement_ );
```

is not working.

And, I have researched on google which says maybe we have to use jquery plugin. I don't know what to do. Please tell me a way to execute scrollIntoView() in IE11 without any plugin.

Comment: Update the question with your relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to execute java selenium code in which I have to scrollIntoView() and for internet explorer it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with executing following script

```
window.scroll(0, document.querySelector('css selector goes here').offsetTop);
```

you could locate elements also by

- document.getElementById(id)  Find an element by element id
- document.getElementsByTagName(name)  Find elements by tag name
- document.getElementsByClassName(name)    Find elements by class name

**Update**

another way (using protractor)

```
await browser.executeScript(`arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'})`, element);
```

Comment: I want to scroll to webElement where should I put or How do I do it?? @Infern0

Comment: I'm not getting it. Please tell me how to use and what is this "await" and "browser" in this solution. Because as per my code - I can pass the selenium web driver and webElement of the element to which I want to scroll.

Comment: as i mention is for protractor, extract the script argument which i provided and just replace it in your code.

Comment: provide a code sample, errors and as much information you can so we can provide proper feedback. All types of js executions above are working for me and for the majority of people.

Comment: I don't have any code sample or error logs for this. But, my question is - on my framework I can't use plugin and scroll into view doesn't work for IE (as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)). So, what should I use to scroll IE horizontally??

Comment: Error: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: The requested mouse movement to (1475, 71) would be outside the bounds of the current view port (left: 0, right: 1366, top: 78, bottom: 728)